# Why do we need to pass local variables through method parameters? Why can't we just declare them within the methods?

Tags: java, methods, parameters

```
public String getAnswer(int number) {
        if(number >= 1 && number <= answers.length) {
            return answers[number-1];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Why do we need to pass local variables through method parameters? Why can't we just declare them within the methods? please see the example given above. We can see the method has an int parameter which it uses for the method. Why is it not possible to declare the local variable within the code?

Comment: Which local variable would you like to declare? With what value?

Comment: But what would be the point?  You want to check `number`, but the method doesn't know what `number` is until you provide?  I'd be like me asking you what type of pie I have without giving it to you....

Comment: please shorten your title. It seem it is interesting question

Comment: One purpose of methods is to compartmentalize behavior for code reuse. The method (potentially) receives some input and performs some action. Method parameters are simply recipients of the input.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible to declare `number` as local parameter (without passing it as an argument). Like,

```
public String getAnswer() {
    int number = 2; // <-- now it's 2.
    if(number >= 1 && number <= answers.length) {
        return answers[number-1];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then to call it,

```
String answer = getAnswer(); // <-- can't pass an argument.
```

You might also have a `field` number,

```
private int number;
public String getAnswer() {
    if(number >= 1 && number <= answers.length) {
        return answers[number-1];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

If you set `number` in your constructor, then you can use it in `getAnswer` without passing it or making it a method local variable (instead, it's class local).

Comment: the op asks for explanation in order to learn no a snippet code that yo posted

Comment: @KickButtowski In what way do I not answer *Why can't we just declare them within the methods?*

Comment: your answer is very vauge to me. : )